# Error: Redirected when going from "/login" to "/home" via a navigation guard. Vue-router and firebase-authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I have an app with Vue.js and Firebase, and I'm using the firebase authentication to login in my app, but i want to create a `beforeEach` method so I can add a verification with the firebase auth works. I want to compare the `displayName` value to let the user sign in, but when i use the `else if` the error appears and doesn't work.

**My router file**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/login'
  },
  {
    path:'/',
    redirect: '/login'
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/quotations',
    name: 'Quotations',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "quotations" */ '../views/Quotations.vue'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ '../views/Login.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/sign-up',
    name: 'SignUp',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ '../views/SignUp.vue')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>{
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if(requiresAuth && !currentUser )next('login');
  else if(!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('home');
  // I want to compare if the user thats is loggin has the displayName === "3" to enter in my app 
  else if(requiresAuth && currentUser && currentUser.displayName != "3")next('login');
  
  else next();
});
```

In the line `else if(requiresAuth && currentUser && currentUser.displayName != "3")next('login');` the error appears, but i don't know how to fix this.

Comment: What exactly is the error? What you've put in the question title above doesn't sound very error-y

Comment: @Phil I want to prevent the login `if displayName === "3"` but the error appears and don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `else if` condition is always considered and met before your 2nd `else if` since it is less specified than your 2nd. So 2nd `else if` will not be reached. You should switch those.

Comment: The error continue, i switched the `else if` and he goes to home and came back to login showing my app and continue the same error in the console